# How do I get rid of a margin in CSS so my sections fit

Tags: html, css

heres what I put

```
section {
    width: 40%;
}
```

I am making a website that has 2 columns, a column with a facts sections about the website on the right side of the page and the sign up sheet on the left side of the page next to it.

I put width: 40; to make the right side smaller but it makes a margin on the right side and I can't get rid of it to but the sign in sheet there.

Comment: If you add `borders`, `paddings` or `margins` it will affect the calculated width, if you want to keep these while retaining the width then add the `box-sizing: border-box` property

Comment: Chosen an answer yet?

Comment: it's not just that I put a margin width so i can make it a certain size to fit but, when it automatically adds a margin to all sides and I can't get rid of it

Comment: Can you replicate the problem here? http://codepen.io/pen/

Answer (score 5):

Could you post an example on a site like https://jsfiddle.net/ or http://codepen.io/?

But to quickly answer your question, to get rid of margins just do this:

`margin: 0`, if that doesn't work then try `margin: 0 !important`.

I would do something like

```
.sign-up-section,
.facts-section {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
}

.sign-up-section {
    width: 60%;
}    

.facts-section {
    width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: I would definitely not suggest using !important but most likely his div is still active like a block element which when set to a percentage still acts like block element and will span 100% with just the margin will take up the remain 60% so he just needs to float left or display inline-block depending on the use case

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
section {
  width: 40%;
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking seems vague, but if you just want to split your page, then this should work in your CSS:

```
.left
{
  float: left;
  background-color: #0e83cd;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50em;
}
.right
{
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
  height:50em;
  background-color: #9e83cd;
}
```

Creates This:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7ZcQ.png)
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I prefer to get rid of the body margins altogether, then us ID codes to change individual element margins. Use this in your CSS:

```
body  {
margin: 0;
```

It should clear the elements and sub-elements of margins, and then you can come back and individually add margins if you need them. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this shorthand property in your css in starting.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed,  figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,  menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {  margin: 0;  padding: 0;     border: 0;  font-size: 100%;    font: inherit;  vertical-align: baseline; }
```

and also add `*{margin:0;padding:0;}`

Its give same output in all browser. Also its clear all extra space,margin and padding.

For more reference Go to here:

[reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

[normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.3/normalize.css)